# Transitively require other imported library's interface from imported library

Tags: cmake

CMake 3.5

I have an existing external library, which I have made an `IMPORTED` library in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_path(
    FOO_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES foo.h
    PATHS "${FOO_ROOT}"
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    PATH_SUFFIXES include/foo
)
find_library(
    FOO_LIBRARY NAMES foo
    PATHS "${FOO_ROOT}"
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib
)
mark_as_advanced(FOO_INCLUDE_DIR FOO_LIBRARY)
find_package_handle_standard_args(
    FOO REQUIRED_VARS
    FOO_INCLUDE_DIR
    FOO_LIBRARY
)
add_library(Foo::Foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET Foo::Foo
    PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    "${FOO_INCLUDE_DIR}" "${BAR_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}" "${BAZ_INCLUDE_DIR}"
)
set_property(TARGET Foo::Foo
    PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
    "${FOO_LIBRARY}"
)
set_property(TARGET Foo::Foo
    PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES
    "${Boost_LIBRARIES}" "${BAR_LIBRARY}" "${BAZ_LIBRARIES}"
)
```

Programs that link with this particular library need thread support.  Adding thread support to something is fairly straightforward:

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG on)
include(FindThreads)
...
target_link_libraries(something PUBLIC Threads::Threads)
```

I would like anything that links against `Foo::Foo` to automatically include `Threads::Threads`.  But you can't use `target_link_libraries()` on an `IMPORTED` library.  So how do I transitively require `Threads::Threads` from `Foo::Foo`?

I managed to work around this by doing the following, but it depended on me checking to see what properties `FindThreads` sets on `Threads::Threads`.  Is there a better way?

```
set_property(TARGET Foo::Foo
    PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES
    "${Boost_LIBRARIES}" "${BAR_LIBRARY}" "${BAZ_LIBRARIES}"
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:Threads::Threads,INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES>
)
set_property(TARGET Foo::Foo
    PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:Threads::Threads,INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>
)
```

Comment: Did you try [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was quite simple.  I simple needed to add `Threads::Threads` to the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property of `Foo::Foo`.  I have no idea why I had determined that would not work the first time around.